# Extracting genre metadata from audio files

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, avfoundation

I would like to extract the Genre from mp3's or m4a files. The meta data is present, as can be seen in iTunes, and I have managed to pull our some NSData objects for genre, but have trouble mapping anything to a particular genre.

Also, the keys don't compare properly, so my method of finding the correct key is hack really.

My current code looks like this.

```
- (NSDictionary*) getMetaDictionary:(AVAsset*)asset
{

    for (NSString *format in [asset availableMetadataFormats]) {
        for (AVMetadataItem *item in [asset metadataForFormat:format]) {

        if (item.key && [item.keySpace isEqualToString:@"itsk"]) {


                NSUInteger akey = NSSwapInt([(NSNumber *)[item key] unsignedIntValue]);
                NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4s",&akey];

                NSLog(@"key: %@ - value: %@", keyString, ([keyString isEqualToString:@"covr"]?@"nope":item.value));

                if ([keyString isEqualToString:@"©gen"])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Genre: %@", item.value);
                }

                if ([keyString isEqualToString:@"gnre"])
                {
                    NSData* genData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:((NSData*)item.value)];

                    NSString* genreString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:genData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Genre from data: %@", genreString);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
 key: ©nam - value: Smokebelch II (Beatless Mix)
 key: ©ART - value: The Sabres Of Paradise
 key: ©wrt - value: Jose Padilla
 key: ©alb - value: Café Del Mar - the Best of (Disc 1)
 key: gnre - value: <0063>
```

My understanding is that the 'gnre' contains the id for the genre. How do you get that ID? How do I map that to an actual ID.

Any help or advice please?

Answer (score 0):

The genre list for ID3 tags can be found here: 
http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0

Check out the Appendix (Section 8).
I'm not sure exactly how Apple maintains their database of tags, but I would strongly feel it was updated based on the link I've included.